# Regex match only if string doesn't contain another string (Ruby gsub)

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match only a single `/` and change it to `\ /` using `gsub`. How can I match only one `/` without matching the other ones?

Sample String:

```
"/* something */   example/123 anotherexample123/456  url/link/to/somewhere  "
```

Expected Result:

```
"/* something */   example\ /123 anotherexample123\ /456  url/link/to/somewhere  "
```

Requirements:

- Trying to avoid matching comments `/*  example  */` .
- Trying to avoid matching urls.
- Only match singular words that contain a `/`.

Thoughts:

- Don't match so that if the captured group begins and starts with a `/`
- Match if it is a singular `/`
- `/(\/)(.*)(\/)/` matches all the pairs of `/ /` that I **DON'T** want and could be a starting point

Use http://rubular.com/ to test

Comment: If you want to change only one instance, why do you insist on using `gsub`?

Comment: (1) What kind of "comments" do you not want to match? (2) What is the format for urls? (3) Words don't (usually) contain a slash. Your string `example` does not contain a slash, it is followed by one. (4) Detecting the number of a noun cannot be done (easily) with a regex. The English plural rule is too complicated for that.

Comment: its not changing only one instance its changing about 70. 
1. code comments that begin with /* and end with */
3. Its not just words. the match I want could be on something123/4567

Answer (score 1):

you could use this pattern

```
(?<!\/)\b([^\/ ]+)\/([^\/ ]+)\b(?!\/)
```

and replace with

```
$1\\ \/$2
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/284)

```
#    (?<!\/)\b([^\/ ]+)\/([^\/ ]+)\b(?!\/)
(?<!            # Negative Look-Behind
  \/            # "/"
)               # End of Negative Look-Behind
\b              # <word boundary>
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^\/ ]        # Character not in [\/ ] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
\/              # "/"
(               # Capturing Group (2)
  [^\/ ]        # Character not in [\/ ] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (2)
\b              # <word boundary>
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
  \/            # "/"
)               # End of Negative Look-Ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do an assumption and say you only want to match / if they are within a sentence and used instead of space like the example you provided above : example1/l123

you could use this pattern to match them:

```
"(?<=\w{1,})/(?=w{1,})"
```

while

```
(?<=            # Positive Look-Behind
\w{1,}         # Match up to one of [a-z], [A-Z] and [1-9]
\              # match \
(?=            # Positive look-Ahead
\w{1,}         # Match up to one of [a-z], [A-Z] and [1-9]
```